# How patches are released for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have a doubt, how patch are given by magento.

SUPEE-10752 (Added Jun 27, 2018)
SUPEE-10888 (Added Sep 18, 2018)
SUPEE-10975 (Added Nov 28, 2018)

Whether that latest patch 10975 included the previous
patches(10752, 10888)

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge i don't think it contain previous patch magento released patch to fix some impotent bugs and issue which can harm our eCommerce system or they introduce new security feature which help us to protect our eCommerce system.But yes there is one more thing if there is any issue generated cause of previous patch they will release a new patch for that.All information are shared by magento in it's description. You can check magento patches from here:
[Magento Security Patches](https://magento.com/security).

Hope this Information helps.